# Moshes parents and sister Miriam

Tags: chumash

Until what age was Moshe being raised by his parents ?

How long was Miriam a significant influence on Moshe?

Comment: He was only home for 3 months, though he probably was able to stay in touch until he ran away from Pharaoh.

Comment: His mother nursed him until much later but that is not exactly "being raised"